# Is there any effective way to read dynamic size shared memory segment using JNA?

Tags: java, c, arrays, struct, jna

I was trying to find effective way to read shared memory in form of array of struct (in C):

```
typedef struct the_struct {
    int id;
    int data;
} the_c_struct;
static the_c_struct *the_struc_ptr = NULL;
```

Currently I use following JNA `Structure` code to retrieve the data from shared memory:

```
public class MyCStruc extends Structure {

    public int id;
    public int data;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"id", "data"});
    }

    @Override
    public void useMemory(Pointer m, int offset) {
        super.useMemory(m, offset);
        super.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void useMemory(Pointer m) {
        super.useMemory(m);
        super.read();
    }

}
```

And read shared memory using native implementation of `shmget` and `shmat`:

```
memId = NativeLib.INSTANCE.shmget(0x999, memSize, 0);
CStructPtr = NativeLib.INSTANCE.shmat(memId, null, 0);

MyCStruc cs=new MyCStruc();
for (int i=0;i<CStructArraySize;i+=8) {
    cs.useMemory(CStructPtr,i);
    // to read a record of struct array
    // do something with the data
}
```

Above code is actually worked, but I guess I can do something more effective to read array of struct? right?

**Note**: size of array of struct is dynamic, but I can managed to get the size of the shared memory.

Comment: Sorry, why is i+=8 in the for loop?

Comment: @terencehill That is because the struct size is 8 in bytes; so to access every struct in the array I do the offset indexing based on the size of struct.

Comment: Maybe in this case it is always equal to 8 but are you aware of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: @terencehill Yes, that would be next problem when it comes to struct data processing. I'm sure JNA already provide some nice implementation to handle correct data alignment.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example07.html) example. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Have you looked at NIO buffers?  You can also access the stuff directly with `Pointer`, no need for the extra `Structure` overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with a `Structure` here, just have the `shmat` call return a `Pointer` and use `Pointer.getInt(0)` to get the ID and `Pointer.getInt(4)` to get the `data` field.

You can even use `Native.getDirectBufferPointer()` to give you an NIO buffer that you can pass off to other Java code.

If you're reading an array of contiguously allocated `struct`, then you should create your first `Structure` using the `Pointer`-based constructor, then invoke `Structure.toArray(size)` on that instance to load the full array.

```
Pointer p = lib.shmat();
MyCStruc s = new MyCStruc(p);
MyCStruc[] array = (MyCStruc[])s.toArray(size);
```

And the constructor:

```
public class MyCStruc extends Structure {
    public MyCStruc(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I'll test it on my environment. In addition does 'Pointer' aware of endianess?

Comment: If the memory for some reason has different endianness than the JVM there might be an issue.  NIO Buffer has some options around that, but I don't know if you can tweak them after the buffer is created.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code:

```
memId = NativeLib.INSTANCE.shmget(0x999, memSize, 0);
CStructPtr = NativeLib.INSTANCE.shmat(memId, null, 0);
CStructArraySize=memSize/8;
MyCStruc cs=new MyCStruc(CStructPtr);
MyCStruc[] acs=(MyCStruc[])cs.toArray(CStructArraySize);
int i=0;
while (i<CStructArraySize) {
    System.out.printf("id=%d data=%d\n", acs[i].id, acs[i].data);
    // do something else with the data
    i++;
}
```

`MyCStruc` now:

```
public class MyCStruc extends Structure {
    public int id;
    public int data;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"id", "data"});
    }
    public MyCStruc(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }
}
```